# How to convert Angular material date value to ISO format?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-material2

I am trying to convert the date set by MaterialDatePicker to ISO format like the default `input[date]`.

What am trying to achieve is I have a `formControl` and inside it, the date should get stored as `YYYY-MM-DD`. Isn't there any attribute or function by Angular Material to achieve this? I have read many answers but everything has a big approach. I have developed a small way to achieve this but I don't think it's an efficient solution. Below is my solution for the same:

app.component.html

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="date1" readonly />
  <mat-hint>{{this.form.get('date1').value}}</mat-hint> <!-- The value I get -->
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
</form><br>
{{this.form.get('date2').value}} <!-- The value I want -->
```

app.component.ts

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

form = this.fb.group({
  date1: [''], date2: ['']
});

ngOnInit() {
  this.form.get('date1').valueChanges.subscribe(value => this.form.patchValue({
    date2: new Date(value).toISOString().split('T')[0]
  }));
}
```

Although my solution works, I have 3 questions in mind:

1. Why should I use 2 controls for 1 field?
2. On `valueChanges`, can I update the value on the same field? I tried this but got this error - `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` which I think is justifiable.
3. Any short trick that can work?

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5jhpqn?file=src/app/app.component.ts) example that I tried.